# Why does the ASP.NET Core MinLength attribute not add an HTML minlength attribute while MaxLength does?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

In my ViewModel, I have the following property;

```
[MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Description must be at least 10 characters long")]
[MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 255 characters")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

In the view, I have the following;

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Description"></label>
    <div>
        <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Which creates the following HTML;

```
<textarea class="form-control input-validation-error" rows="4" data-val="true" data-val- 
maxlength="Description cannot be longer than 255 characters" data-val-maxlength-max="255" data-val-minlength="Description must be at least 10 characters long" data-val-minlength-min="10" data-val-required="Report description is required" id="Description" maxlength="255" name="Description"></textarea>
```

Comment: I can't find a reason why `minlength` doesn't get added, but the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/29cd71c8f7af272cdced7e941c3cd45a28861428/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L748) suggests that it just doesn't consider that attribute. If no-one comes along with an answer, you might consider posing your question to the ASP.NET Core team.

Comment: After looking it up on their Github issues tab, it seems like they have already been informed of this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20588